# Find closest div that has a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that I have some HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="required another_class">
        <div class="some_class">
            <input type="checkbox" name="some_check" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I find the parent div of the checkbox that has the class `required`? As you can see above, the div has two classes `required` and `another_class`. Therefore something like this:

```
$(':checkbox').closest('div[class=required]');
```

Will not work. I thought I could do something like:

```
$(':checkbox').closest('div').hasClass('required');
```

But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use CSS selector in `.closest()`, just like that :

```
$(':checkbox').closest('div.required');
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also use

```
$(':checkbox').parents('div.required')
```